Configuring Proxy for Storybook (Angular + Vite)
I'm working on setting up Storybook (v8.4.5) with a file upload component that uses Postman Echo API. While the upload works perfectly in my Angular dev environment (port 4200) with this proxy config:
{
  "/post": {
    "target": "https://postman-echo.com",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}

I can't get the same proxy working in Storybook (port 6006). The request hits http://localhost:6006/post but returns 404. I've tried:

Setting proxy in .storybook/preview.ts
Creating a vite.config.ts in the root directory with proxy settings and updating .storybook/main.ts

Any suggestions on getting the proxy to work in Storybook with Vite? Thank you in advance!

I ended up simulating an upload instead.
